# Laravel 5.x and Bootstrap 4.3 handling with tabs and form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have two tabs. Status and Multimedia. Users can share status or multimedia. I am trying to use just one form. How can I handle with tabs and validations? What is the logic of this? Thank you guys.

https://ibb.co/DtpPfnN "Screenshot"

I am using Laravel 5.8 and Bootstrap 4.3 (This form is just and I am trying.)

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('test') }}">
    @csrf
        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-status" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-status-tab">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <textarea class="form-control" id="status" rows="3" name="content1"></textarea>
                 </div>
             </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-multimedia" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-multimedia-tab">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="multimedia" rows="3" name="content2"></textarea>
                </div>
             </div>

             <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Send</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Alright you want to handle tabs ... Now what i'm understanding here is that, you want tabs to be open while validating form inside of it right ? if yes then you might want to play with sessions or `@if(old('tab') === 'status')` (that means saving hidden input values on the top of your form fields and changing values with help of javascript ), Now it's just a theory for now so would you please give this a try if you understand what i'm saying, plus i'm working on that too so if i come up with any solution i will post it right away. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I Did it based on validation error, Please give this a try and let me know if it works

**Route > web.php**

```
Route::get('testForm',function(){
        return view('testForm');
})->name('showTestForm');

Route::post('testForm',function(Request $request){
    $validator = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'name'      => 'required', // Form One Field
        'email'     => 'required', // Form Two Field
    ]);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->getMessageBag())->withInput();
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with([
        'message'   => 'Form Submitted'
    ]);
})->name('submitTestForm');
```

**Blade File : testForm.blade.php**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @if(Session::has('message'))
                    <div class="alert">
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <strong>{{ Session::get('message') }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endif
                @if ($errors->any())
                    {{ implode('', $errors->all('<div>:message</div>')) }}
                @endif
                {!! Form::open([
                    'route' => 'submitTestForm'
                ]) !!}
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item @if($errors->has('name') === true && $errors->has('email') === false || $errors->has('name') === true && $errors->has('email') === true) active @endif">
                            <a class="nav-link  @if($errors->has('name') === true && $errors->has('email') === false || $errors->has('name') === true && $errors->has('email') === true || $errors->has('name') === false && $errors->has('email') === false) active @endif" id="pills-formOne-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-formOne" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Form One</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item  @if($errors->has('name') === false && $errors->has('email') === true) active @endif">
                            <a class="nav-link @if($errors->has('name') === false && $errors->has('email') === true) active @else disabled @endif" id="pills-formTwo-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-formTwo" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Form Two</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade @if($errors->has('name') === true && $errors->has('email') === false || $errors->has('name') === true && $errors->has('email') === true) show active in @elseif($errors->has('name') === false && $errors->has('email') === false) show in active @endif" id="pills-formOne" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-formOne-tab">
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Enter Name">
                           </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-pane fade @if($errors->has('name') === false && $errors->has('email') === true) show active in @endif" id="pills-formTwo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-formTwo-tab">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Enter Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```